# CSV Reading by String Search in java

Tags: java, csv

Hi my requirement is to read CSV file and put into DB.

But CSV format is:

```
----------------------------------------

CSV Name ,ABC
ABC, 3232
ABC, 123,1232,1233,13232


Default lines of data to copy

ABC, 123,1232,1233,13232
ABC, 123,1232,1233,13232
ABC, 123,1232,1233,13232

----------------------------------------
```

In above sample CSV i need to skip rows and start reading CSV from "Default lines of data to copy" String this is my requirement.

is there any way to get this result.

Comment: Just read the file line by line, and only start your manipulation after the default line.

Comment: Show the code you are using to read the csv.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a CSV file I always use a library such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) . Using that library you will get an iterator onto the lines in the CSV so you just need to loop around the lines and test each line to see if it is one you should start at. Have a look at the example for reading a csv file [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read).

Answer (score 0):

Just read file line-by-line (using BufferedReader, for example) and skip lines until you read "Default lines of data to copy". Something like this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your.csv"))) {
        String line;

        // skip lines
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null && (!"Default lines of data to copy".equals(line)));

        // read and insert
        while(line != null) {
            // Parse and inser line in DB                

            line = br.readLine();
        }            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```